# c# LINQ sort a list by a subproperty of a property that is a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have an `Order` class, it consists of a number of properties, one of them being `Course`.
The `Course` object contains a list of `MeetingDays`.
Each `MeetingDay` object contains numerous properties, one of which is `StartDate`.

Now I want to sort (`OrderBy`) a list of orders, ordering it by the `StartDate` property of a `MeetingDay`.

Since an order can have several `MeetingDays`: I also have a date, and I only want to sort by the `MeetingDay` per order that is equal to the date parameter.

So if one order starts at 10 am and ends at 2 pm I want it ordered in my list before another order that starts at 3 pm and ends at 6 pm.

**Edit**

It would be nice if something like this was possible:

```
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(x => x.Course.MeetingDays.StartDate.Date == date.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: Guessing from your description, would something like this work? `myOrders.OrderBy(order => order.Course.MeetingDays.First().StartDate)`?

Comment: I updated my question, as a course can contain several MeetingDays, but I only want to sort on the MeetingDate where MeetingDate.StartDate equals a date parameter.

Comment: That sounds like `myOrders.OrderBy(order => order.Course.MeetingDays.First(day => day.StartDate.Date == date.Date).StartDate)`. Is every `order` in `myOrders` **guaranteed** to contain a `MeetingDay` with the same `Date` as `date.Date`? If not, would you like to filter those orders out?

Comment: Yes, every order is guaranteed to contain a MeetingDay with the same Date as date.Date. I am relatively new to LINQ, but I thought that by specifying MeetingDays.First that it only sorted on the first MeetingDay?

Comment: Excellent, then the above should work, let me know if it does :)

Comment: @olydis just noticed that your comment is actually my answer...did not see it before posting.

Comment: @WulfgarDK: yes, `First` sorts only by the first `MeetingDay` - **but** specifically by the first `MeetingDay` that matches the condidtion provided! Indeed `Single` would be a better match than `First` here, as it will also throw if there is **more than one** `MeetingDay` on the same date - which should not happen, right?

Comment: It should not happen, but if some user makes 2 meeting days, like from 10-12 am and then the next from 1 pm to 5 pm, then it wouldn't be possible? Anyway, I think I am going to prevent that possibility from happening.

Comment: My question has been answered, so how do I accept an answer or upvote or whatever I need to do?? Thanks for all the swift and helpful replies!

Comment: @WulfgarDK: Click the checkmark and up arrows to the left of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since (according to the comments) you are guaranteed, that each `order` contains a `MeetingDay` that matches your given day, the following expression will accomplish what you want:

```
var sortedOrders = myOrders
    .OrderBy(order => order
        .Course
        .MeetingDays
        .Single(day => day.StartDate.Date == date.Date)
        .StartDate)
    .ToList();
```

Should, unexpectedly, there be zero or more than one matching `MeetingDay`, an exception will be thrown at the call to `Single`.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if exactly one MeetingDay.StartDate match date:

```
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(x => x.Course.MeetingDays.Single(y => y.StartDate.Date == date.Date).StartDate).ToList();
```